# Spring quartz schedule expression

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

Java spring scheduler quartz

I have old code with express `schedule="*/10 * * * * *"` i do not understand what does that mean ?

Even after readying the following file can't figure out what does above Cron expression do.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, Fire every 10 seconds.

For 10th second of every minute, use "10 * * * * *"  expression.  It fires once a minute where as " */10 * * * * *" fires 6 times a minute.

Answer (score 0):

That means every ten seconds. Quartz cron expressions begins with seconds. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.